# How to deduplicate rows without an additional table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table containing some duplicates e.g.

```
-- table definition: t(a,b,value)
select a, b
from t
group by a, b
having count(*) > 1;
```

I could do

```
create table x as 
 select a, b, min(value)
 from t
 group by a, b;
delete from t;
insert into t select * from x;
drop table x;
```

but this needs creating a table x which for huge tables becomes impractical.

Comment: Has your table `t` a primary key?

Comment: @JaimeDrq no, only a foreign key `a`, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to retain the tuple having the smallest value for a given `a` and `b` value, you may try:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t
                  WHERE t.a = yourTable.a AND
                        t.b = yourTable.b AND
                        t.value < yourTable.value);
```

The above query might benefit from an index on `(a, b, value)`.  But if you don't already have this index then suggesting it is a something of a moot point, as you would have to recreate the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

> but this needs creating a table x which for huge tables becomes
> impractical

On the contrary, creating a new table with all the distinct rows is the preferred method for huge tables with a large number of duplicates.

Create the new table `x` with the exact same schema as `t`:

```
CREATE TABLE x(a ... REFERENCES ...., b ..., value ...);
```

Disable foreign key constraints checks to speed up the process:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
```

Insert the distinct rows of `t` to `x`:

```
INSERT INTO x(a, b, value)
SELECT a, b, MIN(value)
FROM t
GROUP BY a, b
```

Drop the table `t`:

```
DROP TABLE t;
```

Rename the table `x` as `t`:

```
ALTER TABLE x RENAME TO t;
```

Finally reenable foreign key constraints checks:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0030742e42e40faf36962a23787b861c).